# Session Cache LImiter Solve

Tags: php

How can i solve this problem:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /hermes/bosoraweb167/b2787/ipg.culdesigncom1/SignUp.php:73) in /hermes/bosoraweb167/b2787/ipg.culdesigncom1/php/create_account.php on line 3
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosoraweb167/b2787/ipg.culdesigncom1/SignUp.php:73) in /hermes/bosoraweb167/b2787/ipg.culdesigncom1/php/create_account.php on line 62

Comment: No we have your problem, only the code is missing! (Also did you took a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/3933332)

Answer (score 0):

call `session_start()` before any other code. If you're importing included files before the session, removing the closing php tag in those files `?>` help

If the right actions are not taken and a session should not be created, destroy the session.

`$_SESSION = array(); 
 session_destroy();`

Comment: Specifically where am i to destroy the session

Comment: please just have this link and solve for me the error http://www.culdesign.com/SignUp.php